# Need smooth scroll menu in a Joomla 3 site

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

Some months ago, I rebuilt a Joomla 2.5 site into Joomla 3. The design was nice, but the theme coding was overly complicated, so I just put the design into the default theme. The one thing that is different is that the old theme had a smooth scrolling menu.

I see that there is one paid extension available, but there is no demo for me to be sure it provides the functionality I need.

Does anyone have any resources for code to provide that effect. I'm not afraid of code, but neither am I very savvy about jQuery.

Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you point to an example of a "smooth scrolling menu" to make it more clear what you are after?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately the original site was hacked because it was on an insecure web host, so I don't have it as an example. But the menu dropped down slowly, instead of just being there on hover, if that makes any sense.